# Op-amp homework question using potentiometer with my attempt at solving it

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, analog, homework

[image: Image of homework question]

I nearly understood that when Rpot is 0, Vo is highest and when Rpot is 0, Vo is lowest.

So I tried KCL to get Vo when Rpot is 0 (0 turns).

[image: My attempt at solving the question]

I couldn't get Vo but just 0 volts. What mistake did I make?

Comment: *when Rpot is 0, Vo is highest and when Rpot is 0, Vo is lowest* <--- doesn't make sense.

Comment: That's not how potentiometres work. It's still a 100k pot.

Comment: The op-amp is just a buffer and can basically be ignored. So you're left with 3 series resistors with 30V across them. Use Ohm's law to calculate the voltage on top of the lower 25K resistor and the bottom of the top 25K resistor.

Comment: It looks like you're considering that the total resistance of the pot would change. Like the answers show, that's not what happens; instead, it's just split in two. But you could take a pot and connect the wiper to one end, which in effect would make the resistance between the two ends vary as the wiper was moved.

Answer (score 5):

The trick with circuits involving a potentiometer is to replace the pot-meter by a resistor network whose values depend on the wiper position:

[image]

So you see than when \$k=0\$, the wiper is on the upper position 1 and the low-side resistance is the pot-meter value. On the opposite, when \$k=1\$, the wiper is in the lower position 2 and the low-side resistance is 0 ohm while the upper one is now the pot-meter value. Following this method and considering the superposition theorem, you should be able to adapt it to a 20-turn potentiometer and answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to EE.SE. As is the standard practice here, we usually don't provide full solutions to these type of questions. From your drawing, it's clear that you already understood that the ideal op. amp. is just a voltage follower.

What seems to be missing is the understanding that the total resistance of the potentiometer doesn't change, only the "middle tap" changes its position, as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIOWW4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

At the limits, one of the "resistors" that add up to form the potentiometer will be zero.

Comment: Thank you the circuit you drew is super easy to understand. you are my hero

Comment: @BakGwangjin, there's an "accept" button below the up/down vote buttons. You should click that to mark the question solved. You can also upvote this and any other useful answers.

Comment: @BakGwangjin - While Transistor is correct about the "Accept" button, you should generally wait 24 hours or so before hitting it. You never know, somebody else might provide a better answer. No offense intended to vangelo - I was speaking generally.

Answer (score 2):

First, the OP-Amp is in a buffer or unity follower configuration. This means that the output voltage, Vo, will be equal to whatever is at the non-inverting terminal of the op-amp. To find the range of Vo is to just find range of V+ (non inverting voltage)

Then, V+ will vary according to the potential divider formed by the two 25K resistors and the 100K pot. The extremities of variation, which will give the range will be when the resistor is at 0 ohm and 100k ohm with respect to either terminals of the pot.

At 0 ohm with respect to the lower terminal of the potentiometer, the voltage divider formed will be 25K + 100K (above) and 25K + 0 (below). Voltage across the divider is 30V so V+ = (25/(125+25))*30 = 5V.

But we take the voltage wrt ground which will be 5-15 V = -10V (when doing the voltage divider we  made it as if the -15V point was at ground, so we add -15V back to return the voltages to ground reference.
Using the same thinking you can calculate for the second case and arrive at a value of +10V

So the range is from -10V to +10V

Turning the pot.
The full 20 turns of the pot will vary the resistance from 0 ohm to 100K. The pot given is a wiper port so i will assume that it has a linear variation of turning with resistance. so for a single turn from zero, the change will be 100K-0 / 20 = 5K change per turn

Now for the single turn we divide the pot into a 5K and a 95K resistors and proceed with voltage divider calculations as we did in finding the range of Vo. This gives a value of -9V.
For the change the voltage changed from -10V (not turned) to -9V (single turn) which is a change of 1V. Since the pot is linear we can say that

it will change Vo by a volt for each turn.

Comment: Please don't hand out solutions to homework questions. We do not want this to become a homework solution service.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson, Please do not interrupt the desire of the participants here to explain the topic comprehensively. Homework or not, this is an interesting problem in op-amp circuits... especially those with bipolar power supply. No one here benefits from such a formal attitude to circuit ideas. On the contrary, it is rather this type of thinking that should be stimulated... Also, as you can see, this is the third answer to the question and it is perfectly acceptable to give comprehensive information in it...

Comment: You can format your answers better when math is involved: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

The answers so far are comprehensive and in-depth, but it would be interesting to try to see in this network something more than the 19th century potentiometer, which makes it widely applicable in op-amp circuits. Here are some more original points of view in this direction...

**1. Composite potentiometer.** The constant 25 k resistors can be considered as extensions of the potentiometer ends (as if the wiper stops when reaches them). Thus the whole network of three resistors can be considered as a single potentiometer with limited movement of the wiper at the ends.

**2. Resistor summer.** The humble potentiometer is a special case of this network because only one of its end terminals is supplied with voltage; the other is grounded. Here, both potentiometer ends are supplied with equal voltages with opposite polarities. The output voltage of this *split-supplied voltage divider* is referenced to ground (the middle point between the sources)... and it is a weighted sum of the two voltages. It is zero if the wiper is exactly in the middle (it can be found by the superposition principle).

**3. Virtual ground.** So the potentiometer's wiper acts as a (bad) *virtual ground*. It is buffered by the op-amp follower and its output acts as a (perfect) *buffered virtual ground*.

**4. R1-R2 network.** The same summing network can be seen in the circuit of an *inverting amplifier* where it is "stretched" between the input voltage and the op-amp output voltage with opposite polarity.

**5. Differential load.** Another example can be a potentiometer connected between the emitters of a transistor differential pair.

I would be glad if you add more applications of this split-supplied resistor network.

Here is a fun [Wikibooks story](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Idea/Walking_along_the_Resistive_Film) about this network that we created with my students in 2008.

[image: Voltage diagram of a split-supplied potentiometer]